# Limit the output of financial indicators list

Tags: finance

Imagine I have a list of Forex data as below:

```
data= {{"2014 06 30  07:49", {1.36535, 1.36525, 1.36543, 1.36542, 81}}, 
       {"2014 06 30  07:50", {1.36543, 1.3654, 1.36545, 1.36544, 25}}, 
       {"2014 06 30  07:51", {1.36544, 1.36544, 1.36562, 1.36552, 116}}
```

The list has different sizes in different case.
Then using `FinancialIndicator["WildersMovingAverage", i][data]` you can get a 
list of `WildersMovingAverage` given period `i`. The output of this function is a list.

My question is how one may limit the function in order to just compute the value of `WildersMovingAverage` for last data point and not to compute the whole list which is time consuming when the list is huge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs on [WildersMovingAverage](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/indicator/WildersMovingAverage.html)

> [image: Blockquote]

That is, the second argument is the number of periods used in calculating the moving average. So, we can pass the last `n` periods of the data to the function `FinancialIndicator["WildersMovingAverage", n]` to get the "last" value of the indicator:

```
 data = FinancialData["MSFT", {{2009, 1, 1}, {2009, 3, 31}}]; 
 FinancialIndicator["WildersMovingAverage", 5][data[[-5 ;;, 2]]]
 (* {15.842} *)
 FinancialIndicator["WildersMovingAverage", 10][data[[-10 ;;, 2]]]
 (* {15.556}*)
```